# Combining layouts in mxGraph

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

I use hierarchical layout as a default for my page. I want to use some vertices ("2") as a containers for other elements ("2.1"..."2.3").

How can I achieve that?

```js
var graph = new mxGraph(document.getElementById('graphContainer'));
var layout =  new mxHierarchicalLayout(graph);

graph.getModel().beginUpdate();
try {
  var parent = graph.getDefaultParent();
  var v0 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, "0", 0, 0, 240, 30);
  var v1 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, "1", 0, 0, 240, 30);

  graph.insertEdge(parent, null, null, v0, v1);

  var v2 = this.graph.insertVertex(parent, null, "2", 0, 0, 240, 30, 'o1');
  graph.insertEdge(parent, null, null, v1, v2);

  graph.insertVertex(v2, null, "2.1", 0, 0, 220, 30);
  graph.insertVertex(v2, null, "2.2", 0, 0, 220, 30);
  graph.insertVertex(v2, null, "2.3", 0, 0, 220, 30);

  var v3 = this.graph.insertVertex(parent, null, "3", 0, 0, 240, 30);
  graph.insertEdge(parent, null, null, v1, v3);

  layout.execute(parent);

} finally {
  graph.getModel().endUpdate();
}
```

```html
<script src="http://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/src/js/mxClient.js"></script>
<div id="graphContainer" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The section between the `beginUpdate()` and `endUpdate()` is all one compound operation. mxGraph updates the model on each change, but only fires the model changed events and redraws after `endUpdate()`.

So you can just call the layouts in turn and it'll occur as one undoable operation.

If you're laying out from the child-most cells to the top-most container, you might need to switch:

```
mxHierarchicalLayout.resizeParent

mxHierarchicalLayout.moveParent
```

to `true`. See the [relevant entries in the class API specs](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/layout/hierarchical/mxHierarchicalLayout-js.html) for more details.

Comment: I tried to to draw '2.1'...'2.3' after layout.execute with suggested switches. It works better but not as expected. The position is improved but it still doesn't resize the conteiner ('2'). Plus it will be hard to separate my logic and draw main hierarchical graph separately from the children.

Comment: @Amihay sorry but it's hard to remember today. Most likely we switched to different strategy because I didn't update the post with a solution.